# Katepart - "Wrap dynamic at static word wrap marker" as a toolbar button or Kate command?

Tags: command-line, kate

I heavily use Katepart-based editors, like Kate and Kile, for work and personal use. Katepart offers two different word wrap modes, **static** and **dynamic**: in static word wrap mode, a new line is created when a line of text reaches a certain number of characters, by default 80. This mode is enabled from `Configure -> Editor -> Editing` (from which, incidentally, also the number of characters is editable).

In dynamic word wrap mode, new lines are only created by the user, but the software will simulate a new line when the text reaches the edge of the program window; resizing the window, of course, changes the position at which the text is dynamically wrapped. Dynamic word wrap can be activated via `Configure -> Editor -> Appearance`.

There seems to be also a hybrid form of wrapping, that can be activated again via `Configure -> Editor -> Appearance`, which is activated checking the option `Wrap dynamic at static word wrap marker`. This dynamically wraps the text at the static wrap limit.

I find the static wrapping much more readable compared to the long lines given by having the program full screen and dynamic word wrapping active; at the same time, though, I do not like static wrapping, because I don't like having newlines every time the 80 char limit is reached. The hybrid wrapping option is thus perfect for me...but there are times at which I'd like to switch to longer lines. I tried to add a toolbar button for the `Wrap dynamic at static word wrap marker` option, but I couldn't find it. Does anybody know if there's some Kate command, issued by pressing F7 to summon the command line, that toggles this option?

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite the same, but you can press F10 to toggle dynamic word wrap on and off. If "Wrap dynamic at static word wrap marker" is enabled, this switches between dynamic word wrapping at the static word wrap marker and no word wrapping at all (with a horizontal scrollbar for lines that are too long).

This is valid for Kate 19.12.3 that comes with Ubuntu 20.04.4, where F10 is by default assigned to the "Dynamic Word Wrap" action. You can also add a toolbar button for that action.